# The legend is not displayed correctly (text cut off) You can test it with jsbin

Tags: d3.js, charts, legend

I use d3 and xchart.

You can see and test the problem:

http://jsbin.com/ewiwag/118/edit

http://jsbin.com/ewiwag/118/edit?html,output

Thanks a lot!

(The error is not the width css)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have the solution:

You have to adjust this options:

"Width"

and

"axisPaddingLeft":5,
"paddingLeft":188,